# Installed JDBC drivers into Solr

Tags: mysql, postgresql, solr, jetty, jdbc

I am running Solr4 on Jetty9 and I am trying to include the JDBC drivers for both MySQL and PostgreSQL. I'm a little confused about how I do this.

I believe these to be the two files I need:

```
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.tar.gz
http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar
```

I am a little confused about where to put these files, in which folder I should be putting them. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can add the .jar files into `$jetty.home/lib`, however there are several alternatives as well:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html

Another location could be the `lib` subdir of the `solr/home` directory.